# Sum and place it elsewhere in R

Tags: r, sum

I have one column with 950 numbers. I want to sum row 1:40 and place it in a new column on row 50, then sum row 2:41 and place it on row 51 in the new column and so on. How do I do?

Comment: Better don't do it that way. Instead create a new summary table that contains (only) the summarized values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `RcppRoll::roll_sum()`

Hope this helps:

```
r   <- 50
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = 1:951)
v1  <- RcppRoll::roll_sum(df1$c1, n=40)
df1$c2 <- c(rep(NA, r), v1[1:(nrow(df1)-r)])
View(df1) # in RStudio
```

You decide what happens with the sum from row 911 onwards (I've ignored them)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RcppRoll::roll_sum()` and `dplyr::lag()`...

```
df <- data.frame(v = 1:950)

library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)

range <- 40  # how many values to sum, i.e. window size
offset <- 10  # e.g sum(1:40) goes to row 50
df <- mutate(df, roll_sum = RcppRoll::roll_sum(lag(v, n = offset), 
                                        n = range, fill = NA, align = "right"))

df[(range+offset):(range+offset+5), ]
#     v roll_sum
# 50 50      820
# 51 51      860
# 52 52      900
# 53 53      940
# 54 54      980
# 55 55     1020

sum(1:range); sum(2:(range+1))
# [1] 820
# [1] 860
```